# RegionIntersection fails with Lines in 3D

Tags: graphics3d

I have 2 intersecting Lines emerging from the same point and I want to fined the point of intersection.
The function RegionIntersection found the origin point but failed to find the intersection.

What am I missing?

The points of the first line

```
In[278]:= radial[[5]]

Out[278]= {{-0.00548926, 0.256565, 0.103662}, {-0.00531428, 0.256296, 
  0.104157}, {-0.00500216, 0.255807, 0.105072}, {-0.00489756, 
  0.255665, 0.105292}, {-0.0047833, 0.255507, 0.10554}, {-0.00437606, 
  0.254945, 0.106429}, {-0.00399892, 0.254423, 
  0.107267}, {-0.00380427, 0.254162, 0.107591}, {-0.00352772, 
  0.253792, 0.108051}, {-0.00314683, 0.253281, 
  0.108689}, {-0.00286464, 0.252903, 0.109156}, {-0.00244156, 
  0.252314, 0.109731}, {-0.00188609, 0.251539, 0.110478}, {-0.001698, 
  0.251277, 0.110732}, {-0.00154332, 0.251059, 
  0.110934}, {-0.000930818, 0.250156, 0.111646}, {-0.000301051, 
  0.249206, 0.11234}, {-0.000152977, 0.248982, 
  0.112503}, {-0.000103015, 0.248904, 0.112553}, {-7.58942*10^-19, 
  0.248744, 0.112658}, {0.00062729, 0.247733, 0.113236}, {0.00122128, 
  0.246723, 0.113708}, {0.00139597, 0.246426, 0.113847}, {0.00156536, 
  0.246124, 0.113958}, {0.00211934, 0.245082, 0.114245}, {0.00272074, 
  0.243861, 0.114451}, {0.00276676, 0.243768, 0.114467}, {0.00279988, 
  0.243695, 0.114471}, {0.0032928, 0.242528, 0.114424}, {0.00356601, 
  0.241792, 0.1143}, {0.00367556, 0.241454, 0.114207}, {0.00385001, 
  0.240779, 0.113927}, {0.00390934, 0.240549, 0.113832}, {0.0039271, 
  0.240456, 0.113777}, {0.00400802, 0.239801, 0.113289}, {0.00401798, 
  0.239526, 0.113034}, {0.00400263, 0.239164, 0.112641}, {0.00395789, 
  0.238733, 0.112123}, {0.00393484, 0.238587, 0.111934}, {0.00389593, 
  0.238408, 0.111683}, {0.00382816, 0.238052, 0.111202}, {0.00368209, 
  0.237532, 0.110422}, {0.00367865, 0.237517, 0.110401}, {0.00367653, 
  0.237508, 0.110388}, {0.00366286, 0.237472, 0.11033}, {0.00352404, 
  0.237062, 0.10969}, {0.00348231, 0.236983, 0.109544}, {0.00332247, 
  0.236606, 0.108904}, {0.00322043, 0.236485, 0.108639}, {0.00308759, 
  0.236176, 0.108092}, {0.00298657, 0.236017, 0.107782}, {0.0028773, 
  0.235665, 0.107181}, {0.00282901, 0.235545, 0.10697}, {0.00276454, 
  0.235131, 0.106299}, {0.00275378, 0.235065, 0.106192}, {0.00275267, 
  0.235041, 0.106156}, {0.00273643, 0.234589, 0.105455}, {0.0027417, 
  0.234305, 0.105023}, {0.00275146, 0.234126, 0.104756}, {0.0027644, 
  0.233897, 0.104414}, {0.00275471, 0.233691, 0.104089}, {0.00273723, 
  0.233542, 0.103842}, {0.00272372, 0.233289, 0.103443}, {0.00268182, 
  0.23298, 0.102924}, {0.00266453, 0.232915, 0.102803}, {0.00265219, 
  0.232878, 0.10273}, {0.00257063, 0.232574, 0.102163}, {0.00251045, 
  0.232384, 0.101792}, {0.00247678, 0.232249, 0.101547}, {0.00240055, 
  0.231971, 0.101025}, {0.00239328, 0.231935, 0.100964}, {0.00234777, 
  0.231706, 0.100568}, {0.00232953, 0.231625, 0.100424}, {0.00232784, 
  0.231612, 0.100404}, {0.00229992, 0.23129, 0.0999381}, {0.0023008, 
  0.231253, 0.099895}, {0.00232281, 0.230906, 0.099526}, {0.00238507, 
  0.230583, 0.0992946}, {0.00241087, 0.23045, 0.0991999}, {0.00241803,
   0.230428, 0.0991925}, {0.00257865, 0.229896, 
  0.0989729}, {0.0026476, 0.229709, 0.098943}, {0.00280702, 0.229263, 
  0.0988495}, {0.00298446, 0.228811, 0.0988369}, {0.00307763, 0.22857,
   0.0988227}, {0.00331601, 0.227985, 0.0988704}, {0.00337344, 
  0.227843, 0.0988809}, {0.00339701, 0.227788, 0.0988911}, {0.0036847,
   0.227109, 0.0990068}, {0.0038557, 0.22672, 0.0991137}, {0.00401063,
   0.226367, 0.0992059}, {0.00434504, 0.225627, 
  0.0994693}, {0.00434531, 0.225627, 0.0994695}, {0.00434586, 
  0.225626, 0.0994701}, {0.00469247, 0.224861, 
  0.0997639}, {0.00484539, 0.224535, 0.0999086}, {0.00505669, 
  0.224084, 0.100107}, {0.00536986, 0.223432, 0.100423}, {0.00542857, 
  0.22331, 0.100483}, {0.00543126, 0.223304, 0.100486}}
```

The points of the second line

```
In[277]:= radial[[6]]

Out[277]= {{-0.00548926, 0.256565, 0.103662}, {-0.00550375, 0.256171, 
  0.103968}, {-0.00552739, 0.255695, 0.104345}, {-0.00554915, 
  0.255279, 0.104675}, {-0.00557676, 0.254884, 
  0.104996}, {-0.00561501, 0.254351, 0.105431}, {-0.00564671, 0.25398,
   0.105738}, {-0.00569849, 0.25339, 0.106229}, {-0.00573293, 
  0.253042, 0.106523}, {-0.00579615, 0.252401, 
  0.107064}, {-0.00583288, 0.252068, 0.107348}, {-0.00590459, 
  0.251385, 0.107929}, {-0.00594372, 0.251062, 
  0.108209}, {-0.00602056, 0.250348, 0.108818}, {-0.00605372, 
  0.250022, 0.109094}, {-0.00611453, 0.249284, 
  0.109703}, {-0.00613299, 0.248951, 0.109967}, {-0.00615757, 
  0.248184, 0.110557}, {-0.00615286, 0.247848, 
  0.110799}, {-0.00612126, 0.247041, 0.111355}, {-0.00608753, 
  0.246715, 0.111556}, {-0.0059751, 0.245844, 0.112068}, {-0.00592312,
   0.245561, 0.112217}, {-0.00573005, 0.244636, 
  0.112676}, {-0.00567149, 0.244412, 0.112773}, {-0.00539998, 
  0.243463, 0.11316}, {-0.00534348, 0.243301, 0.113214}, {-0.00499909,
   0.242371, 0.113505}, {-0.0049472, 0.242259, 
  0.113528}, {-0.00454229, 0.241411, 0.113694}, {-0.00449047, 
  0.241324, 0.113701}, {-0.00402545, 0.240551, 
  0.113758}, {-0.00399552, 0.24051, 0.113756}, {-0.00381107, 0.240258,
   0.113746}, {-0.00347784, 0.239819, 0.113717}, {-0.00342229, 
  0.239745, 0.113713}, {-0.0029642, 0.239224, 0.113614}, {-0.0027097, 
  0.238925, 0.113566}, {-0.00248733, 0.238695, 
  0.113505}, {-0.00224024, 0.238426, 0.113445}, {-0.00202467, 
  0.238218, 0.113376}, {-0.00183125, 0.238026, 
  0.113318}, {-0.00157016, 0.237791, 0.113224}, {-0.00138675, 
  0.237619, 0.113161}, {-0.00112393, 0.237407, 
  0.113049}, {-0.000767899, 0.237114, 0.1129}, {-0.000697285, 0.23706,
   0.112868}, {-0.000658569, 0.23703, 0.11285}, {-0.000262554, 
  0.236769, 0.112635}, {3.1984*10^-18, 0.236594, 
  0.112492}, {0.000427735, 0.236355, 0.112215}, {0.000609709, 
  0.236259, 0.112091}, {0.000949797, 0.236113, 0.111818}, {0.00117471,
   0.236019, 0.111636}, {0.00132813, 0.235969, 0.11149}, {0.00168249, 
  0.235862, 0.11114}, {0.00168291, 0.235862, 0.111139}, {0.00168392, 
  0.235862, 0.111138}, {0.00201396, 0.235808, 0.110725}, {0.00213132, 
  0.235794, 0.110565}, {0.00230455, 0.235797, 0.110277}, {0.00248887, 
  0.235821, 0.109918}, {0.00254941, 0.235832, 0.109792}, {0.00267635, 
  0.235883, 0.109451}, {0.00275244, 0.235908, 0.109261}, {0.00277601, 
  0.235923, 0.109182}, {0.00293644, 0.23601, 0.108684}, {0.00300221, 
  0.236089, 0.108353}, {0.00307036, 0.236147, 0.108081}, {0.00314645, 
  0.236309, 0.107504}, {0.00315473, 0.236319, 0.107462}, {0.00316611, 
  0.236355, 0.107344}, {0.00324649, 0.236497, 0.106826}, {0.00326922, 
  0.23657, 0.106585}, {0.00330197, 0.236695, 0.106183}, {0.00333151, 
  0.236899, 0.10555}, {0.00333363, 0.236904, 0.105533}, {0.00333514, 
  0.236908, 0.10552}, {0.00338269, 0.23711, 0.104866}, {0.00343665, 
  0.237307, 0.104222}, {0.00343721, 0.237317, 0.104192}, {0.00343863, 
  0.237326, 0.104163}, {0.00351481, 0.237519, 0.10354}, {0.00358598, 
  0.237692, 0.102981}, {0.00359122, 0.237718, 0.102896}, {0.0035963, 
  0.237747, 0.102802}, {0.00365948, 0.237909, 0.102285}, {0.00369569, 
  0.238031, 0.101892}, {0.00370657, 0.238097, 0.101674}, {0.00370755, 
  0.238187, 0.101361}, {0.0037298, 0.238277, 0.101073}, {0.00373412, 
  0.238334, 0.100877}, {0.00373508, 0.238454, 0.100455}, {0.0036841, 
  0.238606, 0.0998426}, {0.00368144, 0.238619, 
  0.0997937}, {0.00366991, 0.238637, 0.0997132}, {0.0036439, 0.238785,
   0.0991674}, {0.0035604, 0.238852, 0.0987735}, {0.00341563, 
  0.238986, 0.0980316}, {0.00322836, 0.239038, 
  0.0974851}, {0.00307292, 0.239112, 0.096912}, {0.00288826, 0.239193,
   0.0962583}, {0.00281607, 0.239241, 0.0959217}, {0.00272546, 
  0.239341, 0.0953017}, {0.00267671, 0.239392, 
  0.0949838}, {0.00267068, 0.239427, 0.0947986}, {0.00266653, 0.23957,
   0.0940569}, {0.0027889, 0.239742, 0.0933001}, {0.00281127, 
  0.239774, 0.0931582}, {0.00299387, 0.239936, 
  0.0925296}, {0.00305716, 0.239992, 0.0923133}, {0.00307235, 
  0.240003, 0.092279}, {0.00314354, 0.240051, 0.0921227}, {0.003379, 
  0.240209, 0.0916068}, {0.00341864, 0.240237, 
  0.0915152}, {0.00360913, 0.240348, 0.0912096}}

In[271]:= Graphics3D[{Table[Line[radial[[i]]], {i, 5, 6}], Red, 
  Sphere[RegionIntersection[Line[radial[[5]]], Line[radial[[6]]]][[1, 
     1]], 0.001]}]

Out[271]= 

In[272]:= Graphics3D[{Table[Line[Drop[radial[[i]], 1]], {i, 5, 6}], 
  Red, Sphere[
   RegionIntersection[Line[Drop[radial[[5]], 1]], 
    Line[Drop[radial[[6]], 1]][[1, 1]]], 0.001]}]

During evaluation of In[272]:= RegionIntersection::reg: {-0.00550375,0.256171,0.103968} is not a correctly specified region.

Out[272]=
```

The first image show that the function RegionIntersection successfully found the first intersection, But when I delete the origin point (the first point of each line),  RegionIntersection returns empty-set, thought the lines clearly intersect as can be seen in the plot.
[image: out 271]
[image: out 272]

Comment: Please provide so that we can reproduce the issue ourselves, it is very difficult to troubleshoot issues like these without the ability to reproduce them. Also, please post the code as text instead of images.

Comment: Please do not post images of your work, especially when the images display at a size that make them difficult to read. Please post your actual Mathematica code in the form of text that can be copied and pasted into a Mathematica notebook. Without such, people who wan to helo you will have do a lot of work to reproduce your problem so they can experiment with possible solutions.

Comment: You should provide the data so we can generate the lines. If the region is empty it might be because there is no crossing, possibly due to numerical precision issues near where the intersection should be. But it's possible you could find a point which is very close that minimizes the distance between the lines - see here: https://pastebin.com/RPVYGDyG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines may not intersect perfectly but appear to come within about `10^-14` of each other, though numerical precision issues may be a factor. You can find this point using `NMinimize` over two piecewise linear interpolations of the curves. Here `pts1` and `pts2` are your `radial[[5]]` and `radial[[6]]` respectively:

```
intp1 = ListInterpolation[#, InterpolationOrder -> 1] & /@ Transpose[pts1];
intp2 = ListInterpolation[#, InterpolationOrder -> 1] & /@ Transpose[pts2];
eval1[t_?NumericQ] := #[t*Length[pts1]] & /@ intp1
eval2[s_?NumericQ] := #[s*Length[pts2]] & /@ intp2

(* constrain t,s to 0.1 < t,s < 0.9 so we get the middle crossing only *)
{err, sol} = NMinimize[{SquaredEuclideanDistance[eval1[t], eval2[s]],
 .1 < t < 0.9, 0.1 < s < 0.9}, {t, s}]

(* {2.26456*10^-14, {t -> 0.501307, s -> 0.595269}} *)

closest = eval1[t /. sol]
(* returns: {0.00307438, 0.236155, 0.108051} *)

Graphics3D[{Line[pts1], Line[pts2], Red, Sphere[closest, .0005]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!